# Zip list created by iteration to use in mpld3 InteractiveLegendPlugin

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply mpd3 interactive legend plugin to all suplots in my figure, something like this:

```
d = {'x': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
     'y1': np.random.randn(12),
     'y2': np.random.randn(12),
     'y3': np.random.randn(12),
     'hue': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12,7))


plot_list = ['y1','y2','y3']
sub=1
k = df.hue.nunique()
lines = []
for y in plot_list:
  plt.subplot(1, 3, sub)

  ax = sns.lineplot('x',y,'hue',data=df, ci=None, palette=sns.cubehelix_palette(k, start=.2, rot=-.3))
  handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() # return lines and labels
  ax.get_legend().remove()
  lines = lines + (plt.subplot(1, 3, sub).lines) #this doesn't do anything in the code as it is right now
  sub=sub+1

interactive_legend = InteractiveLegendPlugin(zip(handles[1:], 
                                                 (plt.subplot(1, 3, 1).lines),
                                                 (plt.subplot(1, 3, 2).lines),
                                                 (plt.subplot(1, 3, 3).lines)
                                                ),
                                                   labels[1:],
                                                   alpha_unsel=0.1,
                                                   alpha_over=1.5, 
                                                   start_visible=True, font_size=18, legend_offset=(750, -20))



plugins.connect(fig, interactive_legend)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25, right=0.9, left=0.05, top=0.88, wspace=0.2, hspace= 0.7)

displayHTML(mpld3.fig_to_html(fig))
```

This code works for what I want, but as it is a have to manually add `(plt.subplot(1, 3, 3).lines)` for each subplot I create, which looks very ugly, as in the original code I have 12 subplots.

I imagine there must be very simple way to do this as I iterate through the "for", but I tried things like 
adding the `lines = lines + (plt.subplot(1, 3, sub).lines)` and using it inside the zip and it doesn't work. It ends up applying the plugin only to one of the plots.

I also tried replacing the "+" for a "," but with this the code doesn't even work.

I may be overexplaning myself now, but I believe the problem may be that I need the result of "lines" after the iterations to be something like this:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>],
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>],
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>]
```

But using "+" I get something like:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>]
```

And "," something like this:

```
((([],[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>]),
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>]),
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d240>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20df28>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f16ab20d710>])
```

So neither works.

I tried other approachs to reach this and failed, and as it is hard to see the result of the zip (and the code only seem to work with the zip), I'm out of options

Comment: I've never used the plugin before but based on this [link](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/mpld3.plugins.InteractiveLegendPlugin/), it seems like you may have other construct options